# Qt - Get rid from .dll file missing errors

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, qt-creator

I have created a GUI which requires .dll files in order to work. Here the list of those:

> mingwm10.dll libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
>   QtCore4.dll QtGui4.dll

I have read that I should write

> CONFIG += static

in .pro file. But it does not work. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Qt installation that is built for static-linking for that CONFIG statement to work. The only way to gt a static Qt install is to download the source package and built it yourself.

Now, to deploy your dynamically linked Qt app, just copy those DLL files to the same folder as your built exe file. This may be easier than building Qt statically.